# Enum.GetNames() results in unexpected order with negative enum constants

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have the following enum definition (in C#):

```
public enum ELogLevel
{
    General = -1,  // Should only be used in drop-down box in Merlinia Administrator log settings
    All = 0,       // Should not be used as a level, only as a threshold, effectively same as Trace
    Trace = 1,
    Debug = 2,
    Info = 3,
    Warn = 4,
    Error = 5,
    Fatal = 6,
    Off = 7        // Should not be used as a level, only as a threshold
}
```

Now, when I do an `Enum.GetNames()` on this type I get a string array with 9 elements as expected, but the order is All, Trace, ... , Off, General, which is not what I was expecting.

Here's the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx) for `Enum.GetNames()`:

> "Remarks: The elements of the return value array are sorted by the
>   values of the enumerated constants."

What's going on here? I can change my program to take this "functionality" into account, but I'd kind of like to know why .NET is doing what it's doing.

Comment: I would suggest submitting a bug report to Microsoft.

Comment: It's not a bug anymore, it's a feature that is [now documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx): "The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (**that is, by their unsigned magnitude**)."

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is a known bug with both `GetNames()` and `GetValues()` that was reported [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98147/enum-getvalues), but ended up getting closed as won't fix:

> Yes, this method indeed has a bug where it returns the array of enum values sorted as unsigned-types (-2 is 0xFFFFFFFE and -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF in two's complement, that's why they are showing up at the end of the list) instead of returning values sorted by their signed-types.
>
> Unfortunately, we cannot change the sort order of GetValues because we will break all existing .NET programs that have been written to depend on the current sorting behavior [...]

Looks like you'll have to reorder the values yourself.

Comment: "existing .NET programs that have been written to depend on the current sorting behavior" And this is why you don't huddle onto implementation details.

Comment: Surely if the implementation always-has-been and always-will-be broken in this way then it would make sense for MS to update the documentation so that it matches the actual behaviour.

Comment: @LukeH: Exactly. Even the bug reporter said the same.

Comment: @LukeH: [They *eventually* did](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx). "The elements of the array are sorted by the binary values of the enumeration constants (**that is, by their unsigned magnitude**)."

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the sorting occurs, it may be that it is sorting the values as if they were unsigned, in which case, -1 = 0xffffffff, which is of course greater than 7.

Comment: It's certainly possible, and it seems to explain things, but it would certainly be odd given that the default underlying type for an `enum` is `int`.

Comment: It seems that my guess is confirmed by the answer by BoltClock below.