# Create enum list with order of position within enum, not value

Tags: c#, .net, enums

The below code always orders by the value of the `enum`, but I would like to do it by position in the `enum`.  You noticed `Matchup` is third in the `enum` but with value of 6.  It always comes out of the iteration as last in the list.

```
 foreach (var enumName in Enum.GetValues(enumType).Cast<TEnum>())
            {

}

 public enum RestrictionDetailType
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "0"), Display(Name = "None")]
        None = 0,
        [EnumMember(Value = "1"), Display(Name = "Team")]
        Team = 1,
        [EnumMember(Value = "6"), Display(Name = "Matchup")]
        Matchup = 6,
        [EnumMember(Value = "2"), Display(Name = "Date/Time")]
        DateTime = 2,
        [EnumMember(Value = "3"), Display(Name = "Venue")]
        VenueCourt = 3,
        [EnumMember(Value = "4"), Display(Name = "Games")]
        Games = 4,
        [EnumMember(Value = "5"), Display(Name = "Exhibition")]
        Exhibition = 5
    }
```

Comment: You could make a list of an array of them in any order you want and use that instead.

Comment: Or, create a new Attribute to store display order and order by that in your enumeration.

Comment: @DiskJunky - eh? [`GetValues()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx) is documented to return them ordered "by their unsigned magnitudes"

Comment: The members of an enum are ordered by the indexes. That's how the enum knows how to order it's values. If you want to order them in a different way then you'd either have to assign indexes in the order you want, or add the values to a list or array in the order you want and then use that object instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I stand corrected - good to know!

Comment: It seems like you might want to see if there is a different solution to your problem that doesn’t require enum order, like using custom attributes or something, since what you want isn’t really possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach(FieldInfo fi in typeof(RestrictionDetailType).GetFields()
  .Where(fi => fi.IsStatic).OrderBy(fi => fi.MetadataToken))
    Console.WriteLine(fi.Name);
```

Source: [Sort enums in declaration order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147228/sort-enums-in-declaration-order)

Comment: This may work - but I don't think it's guaranteed. I don't think the C# compilers guarantee the order in which metadata tokens are assigned

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own method, like this:

```
public static List<T> GetEnumValuesInDeclarationOrder<T>()
{
    var t = typeof(T);
    // first type in this array is the data-type of the enum, int32 if not defined
    var members = t.GetFields();

    var result = new List<T>(members.Length - 1);
    foreach (FieldInfo mem in members.Skip(1))
        result.Add((T)mem.GetValue(null));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: [`GetFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx): "The GetFields method does not return fields in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which fields are returned, because that order varies."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right. My fault. Then I think the only way would be adding another custom attribute to the enum-values and sort them by this custom-attribute values.