# Getting an Enum member by its index (not the value assigned to it) in c#

Tags: c#, enums, enumerate

in `JavaScript` world you can get an enum value according to its index in the object (not the value assigned to the enum member, but always the nth member of that enum):

```js
const myEnum = {
    Hello: 1,
    Bye: 2,
    Greeting: 3
}
const value = myEnum[Object.keys(myEnum)[0]];
console.log(value) // it returns 1
```

I was wondering if it's possible to have this kind of behavior in `C#` too.

I am trying to find the nth member of an Enum in `C#` and the values in it are all different and there is no order to them (and that's exactly how I want them to be).

**Update**

```
enum CSharpEnum {
    SomeValue = 4,
    AnotherValue = 2,
    AndAnotherOne = 1
}
```

I get some indexes (like n) from somewhere else and I want to get the nth memeber of `CSharpEnum`. An example:

```
var index = 2;
var member // a way to get the member and it should return 1 (AndAnotherOne)
// because it is the third member (0, 1, 2)
```

**Update 2**
It seems my question is not clear enough so here is a [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GB6xn5) to a dotnetfiddle playground.
In one of the answers there was a `GetValues` method which made a list of enum values but the enum members got rearranged in it.
I have an enum in the playground and I want to get the third (0, 1, 2) member for example which is `Want`. Is there a way I can get that?

Comment: Your example doesn't look like it's showing your intention? What is it you actually want here? Order of appearance in source code or order of values? In order to make your intention clear, you could provide an example of desired result, where the source order is mixed (like `enum { XSecond = 3, Third = 9, First = 1}` I placed the `X` in front of second, so it can't be mistaken for alphabetical order of names)

Comment: I updated the post. @grek40
I hope it's clear now what I seek.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. (as far as I can tell) there is no reliable way without modifying the enum. Typical solutions on the net rely on implementation details that are not guaranteed by the specification or use explicit annotations. If you want a specific order that is different from the ordering of values or names, you should explicitly annotate the enum members with the desired order.

Comment: So it seems I should think of a workaround. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46608102/34092

Comment: There is no *reliable* way to do that. There are various ways based on getting the enum's fields that *happen to work* for current versions of the compiler, but relying on it would be foolish. You can get this to work reliably at compile time if you parse the code yourself with Roslyn rather than inspecting the type, but that's more in the realm of code generators. A C# enum is not (explicitly) an ordered collection of tags like it is in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
public enum myEnum
{
    Hello = 1,
    Bye = 2,
    Greeting = 3
}
```

the [Enum Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=net-5.0) has a static method [GetValues(Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-5.0#System_Enum_GetValues__1) that returns an array `TEnum[]` of the values of this enum:

```
myEnum[] enumArray = (myEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(myEnum));
myEnum value = enumArray[i]; // { [0] = Hello, [1] = Bye, [3] = Greeting }
```

Newer versions of the Framework have a generic overload (since .NET Framework 5.0?):

```
myEnum[] enumArray = Enum.GetValues<myEnum>();
myEnum value = enumArray[i];
```

---

**UPDATE**

The purpose of an enumeration type is to provide a set of named constants having an underlying integral numeric type. These constants are **not** indexed and have no particular order defined. If you want to have them indexed, insert them into an array

```
enum myEnum {
    SomeValue = 4,
    AnotherValue = 2,
    AndAnotherOne = 1
}
```

```
static readonly myEnum[] enumArray = new[] {
    myEnum.SomeValue,
    myEnum.AnotherValue,
    myEnum.AndAnotherOne
};
```

```
myEnum value = enumArray[2]; // --> myEnum.AndAnotherOne
```

See also: [Enumeration types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum)

Comment: Will [EnumsNet](https://github.com/TylerBrinkley/Enums.NET) become obsolete with .NET 6?

Comment: I never used it, but according to the Read.me file of [Enums.NET](https://github.com/TylerBrinkley/Enums.NET), it provides much more functionality than just this generic `GetValues`.

Comment: The problem is the values get rearranged into the proper order
`enumArray = [AndAnotherOne,  AnotherValue, SomeValue]`

Comment: They get rearranged according to their numeric value. But in your example, they keep the original order `{ [0] = Hello, [1] = Bye, [3] = Greeting }`, where `[n]` are the array indexes. If you want the numeric value of an enum instead, you can cast it to `int` with `int i = (int)enumValue;`.

Comment: Would you be so kind to look at the playground I've added to the question? I've updated the question. Maybe now it is more clear what I seek?!

Answer (score 0):

With enum

```
public enum Test
{
    hello,
    world
}
```

Create an array with

```
var enums = (Test[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test));
```

And now it's indexable.

Comment: Yes but not in the right order. It becoms something like this:
`enumArray = [AndAnotherOne,  AnotherValue, SomeValue]`